# How to pull from multiple MongoDB subdocuments using one query?

Tags: mongodb

Here's my structure of a document in MongoDB

```
{
    "_id": "some-record-id",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "f-field-1",
            "value": "some text value"
        },
        {
            "id": "f-user-field-1",
            "value": ["user-1-id", "user-2-id", "user-3-id"]
        },
        {
            "id": "f-user-field-2",
            "value": ["user-1-id", "user-2-id", "user-3-id"]
        }
    ],
    "embeddedData": {
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "user-1-id",
                "name": "user-1-name"
            },
            {
                "id": "user-2-id",
                "name": "user-2-name"
            },
            {
                "id": "user-3-id",
                "name": "user-3-name"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I have an event that a user has been removed from the system. I have only the userID as an input, and need to do the following

- Remove all the user information from every documents `embeddedData.users` array if the ID matches
- Remove that user id from every array value of `data` segments from every document in the collection

I can do that using 2 separate questions, using `$pull` operator. Is there any possible way to do that using a single query?

Comment: something like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/rKylWjH0Lgi or since update https://mongoplayground.net/p/TpJ0TqC7DiY